# Move links within a navbar

Tags: html, css

Hey I have a navbar with a brand img in the middle but the image is bigger than the actual text in the links. I want to have the links )on both sides of the brand img) to line up with the middle of the brand (vertical halfway point) I tried playing with margin and padding but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

HTML of Navbar:

```
<div class="nav">
        <div class="li">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">PHOTOGRAPHER</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
            <a class="hplogo-a" href=""><img class="hplogo-size" src="Images/Logo-Black - Copy.png" alt=""></a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">INVESTMENT + FAQ</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">BLOG</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Related CSS (note I reset the container size and not the logo because when I did the logo there was empty space on both sides since the  was remaining the same):

```
.nav{
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow:hidden;
  display: inline;

}
.li{
  text-align: center;

}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-item {
  margin: 5px;
}
.resize-anchor{
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: 300px;
}
.hplogo-a{
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
}
a{
  display:inline-block;
  color:black;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
a:hover{
  color:#D1946F;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:link{
  color:#D1946F;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-link{
  margin:0px 10px 30px 10px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  line-height: 26.4px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the CSS you've tried? Maybe create a https://jsfiddle.net or a http://plnkr.co ? How big is the image? Is there transparent/white space around the actual image, or is the file cropped tight to the logo?

Comment: Also, file names shouldn't contain spaces, so your image name 'Logo-Black - Copy.png' should be 'Logo-Black-Copy.png' instead.

Comment: Edit your question and add related CSS you've tried.

Comment: I have added related css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a job for a flex box!

Simply give your nested `div` the class `flex-container` and its `a`s the class `flex-item`...

```
<div class="nav">
  <div class="li flex-container">
    <a class="nav-link flex-item" href="#">PHOTOGRAPHER</a>
    <a class="nav-link flex-item" href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
    <a class="hplogo-a flex-item" href=""><img class="hplogo-size" src="https://seeklogo.com/images/H/hp-logo-EEECF99DCE-seeklogo.com.png" alt=""></a>
    <a class="nav-link flex-item" href="#">INVESTMENT + FAQ</a>
    <a class="nav-link flex-item" href="#">BLOG</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and set the following properties to your page's css...

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-item {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

..and voila!

I strongly recommend [clicking here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) for more info on flex boxes, as they are incredibly useful.

Here's the code in action (I suggest running it in full-page):

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-item {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="li flex-container">
    <a class="nav-link flex-item" href="#">PHOTOGRAPHER</a>
    <a class="nav-link flex-item" href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
    <a class="hplogo-a flex-item" href=""><img class="hplogo-size" src="https://seeklogo.com/images/H/hp-logo-EEECF99DCE-seeklogo.com.png" alt=""></a>
    <a class="nav-link flex-item" href="#">INVESTMENT + FAQ</a>
    <a class="nav-link flex-item" href="#">BLOG</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used a rather large logo image to better accentuate the vertical alignment.

Comment: Thanks @Brent Pappas, but now when I change my window size the img gets smaller too. My guess is it has something to do with how the flex is acting with the resizing i put on it myself, since yours seems to not do this, but resizing the img was necessary.  I tried a few things but they haven't worked.

Comment: That's odd. I'm trying to recreate what your describing, but I can't. My only guess is that maybe you could try setting a min-width property on the img to prevent it from getting smaller?

Comment: I can try and make a jsfiddle or whatever its called. How do i add an image that only exists locally in like Images folder? Cuz that's the only reason I haven't made one.

Comment: Lmao, nvm 1 line of min-width:200px; and it fixed it haha. Thanks a bunch mate.

Comment: @BrownBoii333 

Answer (score 0):

Sir  hopefully my answer is helpful for you what i get it you want a navigation in the middle of your navigation bar

```
<div class="navbar">


   <nav class="nav">
       <ul class="ul">
          <li> <a class="nav-link" href="#">PHOTOGRAPHER</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li> 
          <li><a class="hplogo-a" href=""><img class="hplogo-size" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/fb/76/5b/fb765b8752d50de50cfa15203f9a7acd.png" alt=""></a></li> 
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">INVESTMENT + FAQ</a></li> 
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">BLOG</a></li> 
      </ul>
      </nav>
      </div>
```

here is css

```
      .navbar{float: left;width: 100%;position: relative;}
      .nav{float: left;position: absolute;left:50%;transform:translate(-50% , 0 );}
      .hplogo-size{width:50px;height:50px;}
      .nav ul{list-style:none;}
      .nav ul li{text-decoration: none;display: inline-block;}
```

here is [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97apwz5r/1/)